# Link excel with another closed excel with dynamic tab name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a value from another Excel in Excel, but the tab name would have to be dynamic. For example: if in cell A1 of Workbook1 I have a drop-down list with the names of the tabs in Workbook2, I would like that, by changing the option selected in the drop-down list, the values ​​would automatically update.

I tried to use the indirect formula, but it only works with open Workbook2:

```
=INDIRECT("[Workbook2.xlsx]" & A1 & "!A1")
```

Does anyone know of any other alternative, preferably without using VBA? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way without opening the workbook or using vba to open the workbook get the value and close the workbook.

Comment: You could use Get External Data to query the closed workbook